# Library to help parse cTAKES output

Tags: library, nlp, health

I am looking for a library that would provide a set of functions to help parse [Apache cTAKES](http://ctakes.apache.org/)' output (beyond a traditional XML parser).

Example of such functions:

- list all negated diseases.
- list conditional procedures.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.